# How to find intersection rectangle(points) of instersecting rectangles

Tags: rectangles

If I have two instersecting rectangles`[(x1,y1)(x2,y2)][(x3,y3)(x4,y4)]` described by two verticles. How to find a rectangle which is effect of their intasection(**get 2 points where these rectangles intersect**).

Prgramming language does not matter. May be pseudo code.

PS: Rectangles are parallel to the OXY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Rectangle.intersection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersection%28java.awt.Rectangle%29):

```
Rectangle intersection = rectangle1.intersection(rectangle2);
```

2 of the vertices of the resulting rectangle will be the intersection points. You can use `Rectangle.contains` to determine the common points.

See: [Rectangle Intersection Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Rectangle.java#Rectangle.intersection%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)

Comment: I was asking for the algorithm.

Comment: but I got into source code of that class and there is the algorithm.